# Using Google Geolocation JSON

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation

I'm trying to use Google Reverse Geocoding, which takes some coordenates and returns a JSON structure with some addresses. My javascript code is like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?", 
           { latlng: myDevice.Lat + "," + myDevice.Lon,
             sensor: true},
             function (data) {
               ...
           }
         )
```

However, when debugging with firebug, when it gets in the function, it turns out that data is null.
Could someone give me any advice?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what request is actually been made to Google?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely bumping up against the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  You have two choices:

1. Create a server-side proxy to grab the data, then request it via AJAX.
2. Use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

Comment: Yes this is prob the issue. As you say use the api, or maybe google offers jsonp?